Not able to decode standard protobuf encoded data to Avro POJO using Avro ProtobufDatumReader
I am trying to decode the protobuf encoded data in Java, with the objective to serialize it into the Avro POJO.
Testing it out with simple protobuf (Sample.proto):
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "protodecoder.decoder";

message SampleMsg {
    string firstname = 1;
    string lastname = 2;
  }

The encoded data in HEX is:
0a044a6f686e1203446f65

as byte array:
[10, 4, 74, 111, 104, 110, 18, 3, 68, 111, 101]

which decodes to:

{   "firstname": "John",   "lastname": "Doe" }

Now using the Protobuf library, I am able to decode this as protobuf Object:
Sample.SampleMsg message = Sample.SampleMsg.parseFrom(protobufData);

But then I manually need to convert to Avro POJO.
But when trying to convert using the Avro Protobuf library:
byte[] protobufData = new byte[] { 10, 4, 74, 111, 104, 110, 18, 3, 68, 111, 101 };
ProtobufDatumReader<Sample.SampleMsg> datumReader = new ProtobufDatumReader<>(Sample.SampleMsg.class);
GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord> genericDatumReader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(datumReader.getSchema());
GenericRecord record = genericDatumReader.read(null, DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(new ByteArrayInputStream(protobufData), null));

I am getting error in decoding EOF Exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder$InputStreamByteSource.readRaw(BinaryDecoder.java:855)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.doReadBytes(BinaryDecoder.java:372)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readString(BinaryDecoder.java:289)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readString(BinaryDecoder.java:298)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readString(ResolvingDecoder.java:219)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readString(GenericDatumReader.java:457)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:192)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:260)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:248)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:180)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:154)

Now when I try to encode using Avro itself:
Sample.SampleMsg.Builder builder = Sample.SampleMsg.newBuilder();
builder.setFirstname("John");
builder.setLastname("Doe");
Sample.SampleMsg todo = builder.build();

ProtobufDatumWriter<Sample.SampleMsg> datumWriter = new ProtobufDatumWriter<Sample.SampleMsg>(Sample.SampleMsg.class);
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Encoder e = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(os, null);
datumWriter.write(todo, e);
e.flush();

The byte array generated is:
[8, 74, 111, 104, 110, 6, 68, 111, 101]

And Avro is able to decode, but Google Protobuf gives exception:
Exception in thread "main" com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException$InvalidWireTypeException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidWireType(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:142)
    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:526)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3$Builder.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessageV3.java:887)
    at protodecoder.decoder.Sample$SampleMsg$Builder.mergeFrom(Sample.java:494)
    at protodecoder.decoder.Sample$SampleMsg$1.parsePartialFrom(Sample.java:688)
    at protodecoder.decoder.Sample$SampleMsg$1.parsePartialFrom(Sample.java:680)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:158)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:191)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:203)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:208)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:48)

Does Avro ProtobufDatumReader only able to decode what is encoded using Avro library, and not the standard protobuf encoding? Or Am I missing something here? Kindly support.
If yes, is there any other library with which I can achieve the same?

drive-by comment with apologies. Not a Java nor Avro dev. I think the functionality is that you can use ProtobufDatum[Reader|Writer] with Java classes (stubs) generated by protoc to (de)serialize to Avro but you must use the Protobuf libraries so (de)serialize Protobuf messages.This is why you can encode|decode using Avro but not Protobuf.

Thanks for your comment. I am using the protoc to generate the class Sample.SampleMsg. With protobuf library I am able to deserialize  binary stream of protobuf message. But then I need to convert to avro using reflection manually or some library like orika. But facing error in decoding the same stream using avro-protobuf library where its giving error with protobufdatumreader converting to proto pojo or genericdatumreader converting to avro pojo (avro schema generated from proto schema).

Correct.... So the flow is (1) Generate Sample.SampleMsg; (2) Use proto library to unmarshal|deserialize binary proto messages to Sample.SampleMsg; (3) Use ProtobufDatumWrtier to write Sample.SampleMsg to avro (and binary); (4) Use ProtobufDatumReader to read avro (and binary); (5) Use proto library to marshal|serialize Sample.SampleMsg to binary message; or vice versa.

yeah, its just that, this extra serializing/de-serializing will kill the performance. Now looking into something custom.

org.apache.avro.protobuf contains utilities for Protocol Buffers compatibility, especially Avro reader and writers for generated Protobuf classes.
So, you can read and write Avro based on classes generated by Protocol Buffers. The Avro libraries can only read and write Avro, they can not read or write Protocol Buffers, use the protocol buffer libraries for that.
The first result (10, 4, ...) is Protocol Buffers, the second (8, 74, ...) Avro. The first can only be read by Protocol Buffer libraries, the second only by Avro libraries.
If you want to convert Protocol Buffers to Avro, generate Protocol Buffer classes first, then read the data with these classes using Protocol Buffer libraries und write it out as Avro with Avro libraries.
If you just want to map Protocol Buffers to something use a mapper, like MapStruct.
